# Replace all values with NaN in the dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a small dataframe (df):

```
unique  a     b     c     d 
  0    None  None  None  None
  1    None  None  None  None
  2    None  0132  None  None
  3    None  None  None  0231
  4    None  None  None  None
  5    None  None  0143  None
  6    0121  None  None  None
  7    None  None  None  0432
```

I need to replace all values with NaN. I tried to apply `df.fillna(np.NAN)`, but it does not change the value in cells, where there is a number.
How do I make all the values have been replaced?
Dataframe should look like this:

```
unique  a     b     c     d 
  0    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
  1    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
  2    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
  3    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
  4    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
  5    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
  6    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
  7    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: `df.fillna()` kind of does the opposite of what you want. It replaces all `NaN`-values with another value. So `df.fillna(np.NAN)` replaces all `NaN` with `NaN` which makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor and pass index and columns names by `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `loc` to assign `np.nan`

```
df.loc[:] = np.nan
```

---

`iloc` also works

```
df.iloc[:] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to the pool, this also works:

```
df[:] = np.nan
```